# Problems Merging JSON Data -- ObjectMapper (HashMap)

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

I have a JSON file that contains a dictionary. For each English word there is an Object associated with it. Each object is a list of tags and keys. Some sample data:

```
}, 
"On": {
    "ADP": 345, 
    "PRT": 1
}, 
"On-to-Spokane": {
    "ADJ": 1
}, 
"Once": {
    "ADP": 28, 
    "ADV": 57
}, 
"One": {
    "NOUN": 76, 
    "NUM": 343
},
```

I am trying to create a new JSON file where I go to each word in the already existing word-set and take the word's ending. The words ending is placed into a new Map if it doesn't exist already in the new map, if it already exists in the new map, the data from the word needs to be added to the new map.

```
    InvertedStemmerDB data = new InvertedStemmerDB();
    inDict = mapper.readValue(new File(dictionary), Map.class); 

    //Hold Stem Data... creating a whole new look-up dictionary for word endings
    Map<String,Object> stemData = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    //Open up existing data
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    //Map<String,Object> data1 = mapper.readValue(new File("*****.json"), Map.class);


    //Go through All the Data
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : inDict.entrySet()) {

         //this is how I'm stripping the word.. this isn't the issue
        String key = entry.getKey();
        stemmer.setCurrent(key);
        stemmer.stem();
        String stemKey = stemmer.getCurrent();  
        String suffix = suffix(key, stemKey);

        //get whats actually inside this word
        Map<String, Integer> tags = (Map<String, Integer>) inDict.get(entry);

        if (stemData.containsKey(suffix)) {//This means it needs to be updated, the stem already exists

            //get object sub-value
            Map<String, Integer> stemTag = (Map<String, Integer>) stemData.get(suffix);

            double value = 0;
            for (String tag : tags.keySet()) {
                //add to stemData
                if(stemTag.containsKey(tag)){
                    int previousValue = stemTag.get(tag);
                    int resultantValue = tags.get(tag);
                    stemTag.put(tag, resultantValue+previousValue);
                }
                else

                stemTag.put(tag, tags.get(tag));
            }
        }

        else {
            //needs to be created, not updated
                stemData.put(suffix, inDict.get(key));
            }   
    }

    mapper.writeValue(new File("test_write.json"), stemData);
```

After 'fixing' several problems, I"m still getting a NullPointerException..

Sample output:

So, for a sample data:

```
"running": {
    "ADJ": 1
}, 
"dancing": {
    "ADP": 28, 
    "ADV": 57
}, 
"hopeing": {
  "ADJ":14
 },
```

Output will be:

```
 "ing": {
    "ADJ": 15
    "ADP": 28
    "ADV": 57
```

Comment: please post sample output data in json you want to generate.

Comment: @NikolayRusev I added an example at the end of the question. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the culprit :

```
//get whats actually inside this word
Map<String, Integer> tags = (Map<String, Integer>) inDict.get(entry);
```

It should be :

```
Map<String, Integer> tags = (Map<String, Integer>) entry.getValue();
```

Comment: That fixed at least part of it! Now its giving me, Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)

Comment: I guess this means that  a type of null suffix should be counted too? Meaning i need to replace null with some designated key value?

Comment: Indeed, you can't have null keys in a JSON object (though it's possible in Javascript). You need to test the value and, like you said, use a special label.

Comment: Or just skip null suffixes altogether :)

Comment: I thought that this error would have been here:    if(stemKey.equals(null))
    stemKey = "null_value"; ... But its not?

Comment: Don't do that, `stemKey.equals(null)` will always return `false` (it's in the very definition of the `equals` method). Do `if (stemKey == null)` instead.

Comment: I did have the wrong place, changed to    String suffix = suffix(key, stemKey);
   if(suffix == null)
    suffix = "null_suffix";   --- Thanks for the help, I just had the wrong spot